# How to stop Remote Desktop closing a session due to idle time in windows server 2016?

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016

I'm connecting from a Windows 10 desktop  (via RDP) to a server running windows server 2016. Some tasks take very long running processes on the remote server. My problem is that Remote Desktop logs out my session and terminates because of idle time (inactivity).

We have  15 user set-up those who access remote desk from their pcs.

Does anyone know how I disable this behavior for one particular user instead of all?

Comment: If you set the RDS settings via group policy, you could exempt your self from that policy. Or set group policy to give you a different policy.

Comment: @Nixphoe tried doing but not success! Can you share Idea how that can be done.

Comment: use a Mouse Mover to simulate user activity